# Reference to CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this js code to change the background image but I'm unsure what needs to be referenced in the .css file. I read nothing but I am still getting a blank screen.

```
$(function() {
var body = $(‘body’);
var backgrounds = new Array(
‘url(images/bg.jpeg)’,
‘url(images/bg2.jpeg)’
‘url(images/bg3.jpeg)’
);
var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
body.css(
‘background’,
backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length] 
);

setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
}
setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
body.css(‘background’, backgrounds[0]);
});
```

I've also installed jquery by referencing the google CDN.

Many thanks for your help.

T

Comment: I don't think you need a .css file for this. looks like you have smart quotes on in your text editor. you need to turn them off. or use something like sublime text, that has defaults set for getting code(s) working

Comment: Probably the smart quotes as Abdul mentions.  You have `‘background’` and you want `'background'`.

Comment: Ok, I'll change editor (currently coda). Why is body.css referenced?

Comment: `body.css()` is a jQuery function that will update the css of the selected element. the css changes inline, so the element will look like this: `<body style='background: url(someurl.jpg);'> body content </body>`

Comment: Smart quotes was the problem. Working now. Thank you Abdul and @Draco18s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this doesn't have an official answer, I'll answer it, even though this is a repeat from the comments in the question.

The problem was the ‘curly quotes.’ They needed to be 'straight quotes.'

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided uses incorrect quote marks for strings (‘ instead of '), and was missing a comma (,) after the second background.

```
$(function() {
  var body = $('body');
  var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(images/bg.jpeg)',
    'url(images/bg2.jpeg)',
    'url(images/bg3.jpeg)'
  );
  var current = 0;

  function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
      'background',
      backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
    );

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
  }
  setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
  body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

You can see a demo of it working here with colors instead of background images:
https://jsfiddle.net/kb58tvo9/1/

(A tidied up version here: https://jsfiddle.net/kb58tvo9/2/)